# Como concatenar duas listas de maneira eficiente?

Tags: delphi, lista, delphi-xe8

Tendo como objetivo a união representada pela figura:

[image: Resultado esperado.]

Tendo em vista a estrutura abaixo:

```
TMyRecord = record
    Index: Int64;
    Kind: TMyEnum;
    Value: String;
end
```

Tendo duas listas (`Generics.Collections.TList<TMyRecord>`) A e B utilizo o seguinte método para realizar a união:

```
ListA.AddRange(ListB.ToArray);
ListA.TrimExcess;
```

O problema com este  método é que resulta em baixa performance para comprimentos acima de 400 elementos por lista.

Outro requisito seria manter a ordem onde após o ultimo elemento de A deve se encontrar o primeiro de B. Tal ordenação dificultaria o uso de paralelismo.

Sendo assim, qual seriam algumas maneiras eficazes de realizar a união garantindo performance e a ordenação?

Comment: Qual o conteúdo do record?

Comment: Certo vi que colocou a estrutura do record, aí a verificação do que é igual você está fazendo como? (Já entendi que é coisa de compilador, mas eu não sei o que você quer fazer ainda, então não machuca perguntar)

Comment: Não há esse tipo de verificação. Devo simplesmente concatenar as duas listas de alguma forma. É uma parte da limpeza dos _Tokens_.

Comment: Bem, o index creio eu que seja a ordenação da disposição dos teus lexemas, então o que eu te sugiro é o seguinte: ordena ambas as listas, e depois vai iterando passo a passo, sempre mantendo o A com o menor índice. Caso o índice do A seja maior que o do B quer dizer que ele não tem o lexema, e aí você pode adicionar no meio da lista, na posição anterior ao atual da tua iteração. Mesmo com o passo extra de ordenação, se a ordenação for dada pelo índice tu provavelmente vai conseguir desempenho melhor.

Comment: Creio que você não entendeu a pergunta.

Comment: Ah certo, eu reli mais duas vezes e finalmente entendi o que você quer. Esse é um problema bem comum de se usar listas... O método de `AddRange` normalmente não é otimizado em nenhuma linguagem... A primeira coisa que tentaria é fazer `for each` da Lista B dando `Add` na Lista A. Muito estúpido, mas talvez já te dê algum ganho de performance.

Comment: acredito que não tenha muito o que fazer, pois adicionar uma lista em outra é uma operação On, onde n é a quantidade de elementos da sua lista, como você tem que percorrer todos os elementos da sua lista, quanto mais elementos em sua lista, mais demorado será a operação

Comment: Você tentou usar o `addRange` sem converter a `ListaB` para arrray? Deu alguma diferença?

Answer (score 1):

Não consegui reproduzir baixa performance nem com 3 mil elementos por lista. Também a ordem está sendo mantida. Creio que outras coisas estão interferindo no seu código.

Veja o código abaixo:

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Generics.Collections, Diagnostics;

type
  TMyEnum = (meUno, meDuo, meFoo, meBar);

  TMyRecord = record
    Index: Int64;
    Kind: TMyEnum;
    Value: String;
  end;

  TMyLista = Generics.Collections.TList<TMyRecord>;


const
  TamanhoCadaArray = 3000;

var
 ListaA,ListaB: TMyLista;
 ts1: TStopwatch;

procedure PreencheLista(Lista: TMyLista; const nn:string);
var
  I: Integer;
  myRec: TMyRecord;
begin
  for I := 1 to TamanhoCadaArray do
  begin
    myRec.Index := I;
    myRec.Kind := tmyenum(I mod 4);
    myRec.Value := nn+ ' '+ IntToStr(I);
    Lista.Add(myRec);
  end;

end;

begin
  try
    ListaA := TMyLista.Create;
    ListaB := TMyLista.Create;

    PreencheLista(ListaA, 'A');
    PreencheLista(ListaB, 'B');

    ts1.Create;
    ts1.Start;
    ListaA.AddRange(ListaB.ToArray);
    ListaA.TrimExcess;
    ts1.Stop;

    Writeln(ts1.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    Writeln(ListaA[0].Value);
    Writeln(ListaA[1].Value);
    Writeln(ListaA[2].Value);
    Writeln(ListaA[3].Value);
    Writeln(ListaA[4].Value);

    Writeln(ListaA[TamanhoCadaArray].Value);
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```